# working with laravel nested route group

Tags: laravel, routes, nested

I am using middleware for route groups and have three middlewares `admin`, `teacher`, and `teacheradmin`
Well admin is working fine but suppose I have 10 routes and all of them defined under group `teacheradmin` (working case for now)
but I want only 5 of those 10 routes to be accessed by middleware `teacher` and all 10 to be accessed by middleware `teacheradmin`

this is how I nested route groups

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'teacheradmin'], function() {
   //defined 5 routes only accessible by teacheradmin

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'teacher'], function() {
       //defined the other routes accessible by both teacher and teacheradmin
   });
});
```

but the above nesting is not working, `teacheradmin` is not able to access the routes defined under `teacher`

plz I need a direction on how can I make it work

**Update:**
as per the answer I have defined middleware array for common routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['teacher', 'teacheradmin']], function() {
   //defined common routes
});
```

and the handle methods for teh two middleware is:

**teacher**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            if(Auth::user()->user_type != 'TEACHER')
            {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/')
                    ->withErrors('That username/password does not match, please try again !!!.');
        }
    }
```

**teacheradmin**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            if(Auth::user()->user_type != 'TEACHER_ADMIN')
            {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/')
                    ->withErrors('That username/password does not match, please try again !!!.');
        }
    }
```

and the dashboard route goes to this method

```
public function Dashboard(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->user_type === 'ADMIN') {
            return redirect()->route('dashboardadmin');
        } else if($user->user_type === 'TEACHER_ADMIN') {
            return redirect()->route('dashboardteacher');
        } else if($user->user_type === 'TEACHER') {
            return redirect()->route('world_selection');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('dashboardchild');
        }
    }
```

now the problem I am facing is when I am on dashboard and I try to access a common route as `teacheradmin` then it also goes to handle of `teacher` hence coming back to the same page again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you are nesting them. You can attach multiple middleware via array notation to a group like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'teacheradmin'], function() {
    //defined 5 routes only accessible by teacheradmin
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['teacher', 'teacheradmin']], function() {
    //defined the other routes accessible by both teacher and teacheradmin
});
```

**Update:**

I think what you are trying to do can be done by using just one middleware with [middleware parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-parameters):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:teacheradmin'], function() {
    //defined 5 routes only accessible by teacheradmin
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:teacher,teacheradmin'], function() {
    //defined the other routes accessible by both teacher and teacheradmin
});
```

And in the role middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    dd($roles);
    //Do your role checking here
    return $next($request);
}
```

Disclaimer: `...$roles` works from php 5.6 upwards.

Comment: any specific code to be written in middleware handle, as when I try to access any route under 2nd group (common group) as teacheradmin, even then it goes to teacherMiddleware handle and hence not working

Comment: Can you update your question with your middleware code? I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: updated my question, it seems that when accessing common route it goes to the handle of both middleware and hence coming back to same page that is dashboard

Comment: Sometimes it is desirable to keep routes grouped in order to not duplicate definitions such as prefix and namespace, which could be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

As of Laravel 8 I would write it like:

```
Route::group(
    ['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api'],
    function(Router $router){
        Route::get('/', function(){
            return "Did you forget where you placed your keys??";
        });
        Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']); //public
        Route::get('/register', [LoginController::class, 'register']); //public
        Route::group( //protected routes group
            ['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], //protected via some middleware
            function () {
                Route::get('/users', [UsersController::class, 'users']);
            }
        );
    }
);
```